# sub and gsub function?

Tags: r, awk, substring

I have this command:

```
$ find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | awk '{system( "echo "  $(sub(/\//, "_")) ) }'
_home/mol/Pulpit/test/1.jpg
```

Now the same thing, but using gsub:

```
$ find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | awk '{system( "echo "  $(gsub(/\//, "_")) ) }'

mol@mol:~
```

I want to get the result:

```
_home_mol_Pulpit_test_1.jpg
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

I put 'echo' to test the command:

```
$ find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | awk '{gsub("/", "_")} {system( "echo " mv $0 " " $0) }'
_home_mol_Pulpit_test_1.jpg _home_pic_Pulpit_test_1.jpg

mol@mol:~
```

I want to get the result:

```
$ find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | awk '{gsub("/", "_")} {system( "echo " mv $0 " " $0) }'
/home/pic/Pulpit/test/1.jpg  _home_pic_Pulpit_test_1.jpg
```

Comment: Take a look at the `rename` command. There are two versions. One is a Perl script sometimes called [`prename`](http://man.he.net/man1/prename). Another is part of the [`util-linux-ng`](https://launchpad.net/util-linux-ng) package. Either can do the type of renaming you're doing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That won't work if the string contains more than one match... try this:

```
echo "/x/y/z/x" | awk '{ gsub("/", "_") ; system( "echo "  $0) }'
```

or better (if the `echo` isn't a placeholder for something else):

```
echo "/x/y/z/x" | awk '{ gsub("/", "_") ; print $0 }'
```

In your case you want to make a copy of the value before changing it:

```
echo "/x/y/z/x" | awk '{ c=$0; gsub("/", "_", c) ; system( "echo " $0 " " c )}'
```